# Processing SAML response with Spring SAML

Tags: spring, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I developed a Service Provider by using **Spring SAML**.
I've configured several **IdPs**, each of them with a different naming conventions for the attributes.

1. Could I log (on **Tomcat**'s `logs/catalina.out` file) an entire **SAML response** after a successful **AuthN** process?
2. Are there some native features in order to define an association between a certain IdP's `EntityID` and the attribute that maps the returned `userID`?
3. I'm also reading about the **OID format**: how can I properly decode this kind of data?

---

**Update:**

About the first question, according to the documentation, I setup up both debug logging and authentication logging as follows:

```
// Logger for SAML messages and events
@Bean
public SAMLDefaultLogger samlDefaultLogger() {
    SAMLDefaultLogger samlDefaultLogger = new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    samlDefaultLogger.setLogMessages(true);
    samlDefaultLogger.setLogErrors(true);
    return samlDefaultLogger;
}
```

Then, by defining a `log4j.properties` as follows:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security.saml=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.opensaml=DEBUG
```

And by properly configuring the Maven `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Despite that, the complete SAML response doesn't appear (I'm expecting an XML message). The output is as follows:

```
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.985] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- MetadataCredentialResolver: Attempting to retrieve credentials from cache using index: [http:/test.idp.prv/services/trust,{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor,urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol,SIGNING]
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.985] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- MetadataCredentialResolver: Retrieved credentials from cache using index: [http:/test.idp.prv/services/trust,{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor,urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol,SIGNING]
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.985] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry: Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableUsageCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.UsageCriteria
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.986] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry: Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableKeyAlgorithmCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.KeyAlgorithmCriteria
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.986] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry: Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.986] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry: Registry could not locate evaluable criteria for criteria class org.opensaml.security.MetadataCriteria
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.987] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Attempting to verify signature and establish trust using KeyInfo-derived credentials
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.987] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Found 0 key names: []
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.987] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Processing KeyInfo child with qname: {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.987] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Provider org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.RSAKeyValueProvider doesn't handle objects of type {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data, skipping
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.988] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Provider org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.DSAKeyValueProvider doesn't handle objects of type {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data, skipping
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.988] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Processing KeyInfo child {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data with provider org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.988] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- InlineX509DataProvider: Attempting to extract credential from an X509Data
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.993] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- InlineX509DataProvider: Found 1 X509Certificates
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.993] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- InlineX509DataProvider: Found 0 X509CRLs
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.993] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- InlineX509DataProvider: Single certificate was present, treating as end-entity certificate
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.994] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: Credentials successfully extracted from child {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data by provider org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.994] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver: A total of 1 credentials were resolved
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.994] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry: Registry could not locate evaluable criteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoCriteria
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.994] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- SignatureValidator: Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.994] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- SignatureValidator: Creating XMLSignature object
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.995] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- SignatureValidator: Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.995] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- SignatureValidator: Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.999] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- SignatureValidator: Signature validated with key from supplied credential
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.999] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.999] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.999] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
[2014-07-29 14:13:51.999] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- ExplicitKeyTrustEvaluator: Successfully validated untrusted credential against trusted key
[2014-07-29 14:13:52.000] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Successfully established trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
[2014-07-29 14:13:52.000] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl: Processing Bearer subject confirmation
[2014-07-29 14:13:52.000] boot - 1118 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl: Verifying received AuthnContext org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.AuthnContextImpl@3ab2fc5f against requested null
[2014-07-29 14:13:52.001] boot - 1118  INFO [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- PrismaUserDetailsServiceImpl: SAML Response      EntityID: urn:com:vdenotaris:mysp
[2014-07-29 14:13:52.001] boot - 1118  INFO [http-bio-443-exec-38] --- PrismaUserDetailsServiceImpl: SAML Response      RemoteEntityID: http:/test.idp.prv/services/trust
```

Note that the last two lines are defined manually by me.

Answer (score 8):

1. You can use either debug logging ([chapter 6.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf)), or authentication log ([chapter 9.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf)) with `logMessages` property set to `true`. Both are able to log messages to catalina.out (as they just send logs to slf4j).
2. No, you need to implement such logic to your `SAMLUserDetailsService`
3. You can load all received attributes from the `SAMLCredential` object by calls to `getAttributeByName` and `getAttributes`, the returned `Attribute` object contains methods which allow you to parse any received attribute structure. There are no specific parsers included inside Spring SAML.

   The attributes with data in some OID type are typically encoded as `xsd:string` or `xsd:xsd:base64Binary` and you can get the raw string value for both as in the example of chapter 9.4. Providing additional possibilities to parse the encoded string into a corresponding Java type (based on OID) is out of scope for Spring SAML.

Is there some paricular type/OID you're interested it? Are you referring to this [profile](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/28042/sstc-saml-attribute-x500-cs-01.pdf)?

Comment: I should parse this kind of response: http://wiki.infn.it/_media/cn/ccr/aai/howto/attribute-map.xml

Comment: The values in that document are just strings, you don't need any special parsing for them.

Comment: Please, do read the chapter 6.5 in the manual... It contains the following: log4j.logger.PROTOCOL_MESSAGE=DEBUG which will start logging content of your SAML messages.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that line!

Comment: No problem. Btw for some reason I don't see output from the SAMLDefaultLogger in your log, which would otherwise include the decrypted message. You might still want to look into that, it's probably some logging configuration issue. The line should look like: 2014-07-29 15:46:54.676  INFO 7688 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;urn:it:miur:prisma;http://idp.ssocircle.com;;<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF- .....

Comment: Not yet, I'm just returning from the vacation. I'll be at work during next days.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this:

```
log4j.logger.PROTOCOL_MESSAGE=DEBUG
```

Or this for Logback:

```
<logger name="PROTOCOL_MESSAGE" level="DEBUG" />
```